# How do I select rows in my MySQL DB with a datetime of today - 2 days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do this:

```
WHERE dateadded < TODAY - 2 days
```

What is the correct MySQL syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dateadded) > 2